# Not able to print pop up dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to print a popup dialog box. I have tried several times, but I could only get the whole window with popup dialog box, but need to print only the dialog box.

I did find one solution that could print the dialog box, but now it is not showing the values entered in the text box while printing.

Please help me with the code below or give good references to print div values with values inside the text box.

This is the code that I have written to print the pop up dialog.

```
<script>
    function PrintContent()
    {
        var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('scorecard');
        var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow",
        "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
        WindowObject.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
        WindowObject.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
        var str = "<style type='text/css' media='all'>";
        str = str + "MyStyles { text-align: center; }";
        str = str + "</style>";
        WindowObject.document.writeln(str);
        WindowObject.document.writeln('</head><body>');
        WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.writeln('</body></html>');
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for telling us! Please write a new question, this one will get closed soon. But before you ask a new question, [Have a look at the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. At least show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Popup modal

HTML

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap modal box if that is what you are looking for. Here is the code, just paste it in your html file and see if it that's what you want.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#333;">Buy Membership</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p style="color:#777;">You are not a premium member of Pagpry and thus you could use only limited images and features. Buy membership for more features and tools.</p>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="#">Click Here to Know about Membership Plans.</a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
        
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('works');
            $('#myModal').modal();
            alert('works');
        });
        
        
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```